# MySQL performance problem

Tags: mysql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have the following medium size table (less than 3M rows) on a 1 core, 8GB RAM server:

```
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tweetid     | varchar(255)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id     | varchar(255)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| screen_name | varchar(255)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date        | datetime       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| json_src    | varchar(15000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I select rows by user_id, query time ranges from a few seconds to more than 2 minutes, which is completely unacceptable. Initially I thought it was a memory problem, since I do not have this problem when indexes take up less space. So I made sure innodb_buffer_pool_size is higher than the total index size but that did not solve it. As total index size becomes large, some indexes are fast to get, others very slow. It does not make sense to me because all indexes should be fitting into memory.

Many posts seem to be about the same problem, and I tried all suggestions I could find, but nothing worked.

Any idea ?

Edit:

Here is the output of 'show create table name;'. As you can see, user_id is a primary key so it should be indexed.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `tweetid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `json_src` varchar(15000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweetid`,`user_id`,`screen_name`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Edit 2:

The exact command is:

```
  select * from twittertweets where user_id=3678084920 limit 2;
```

With a select in front I get:

```
  | id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys             
  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | twittertweets | ALL  | ix_twittertweets_user_id 
  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2231775 | Using where |
```

Since I created a new table, let me should you the output of 'show create table':

```
  | twittertweets | CREATE TABLE `twittertweets` (
  `tweetid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `json_src` varchar(15000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweetid`),
  KEY `ix_twittertweets_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `ix_twittertweets_screen_name` (`screen_name`),
  KEY `ix_twittertweets_date` (`date`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Seems llike you don't have an index on `(user_id)`. It would help if you provided the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` output.

Comment: Add results of `show create table <tablename>;` to the question, it gives more info than `describe/explain`;

Comment: Just added an Edit to my post - let me know!

Comment: thanks for the additional info, please consider formatting. I've fixed it this time. Also, your userid is added as a second field in the index so wouldn't be used if tweed_id isn't in the query. Last thing, ping @ypercube if you want him to be notified of your reply

Comment: Thanks, Tom! As you can see, this is my first post. @ypercube, I've edited my post!

Comment: @jkavalik, you too!

Comment: `user_id` is a varchar. Use quotes around the literal value: `user_id = '3678084920'`

Answer (score 2):

Using a `varchar(255)` as a 'one-size fits all' type is a bad idea, but that is another story, and not what you asked.

As @ypercube said, you have 2 options:

a) Create an additional index on user_id

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`);
```

b) Reorder your PRIMARY key so it starts by user_id

```
ALTER TABLE `test` DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `tweetid`,`screen_name`,`date`);
```

This second option will take half the disk and memory space, but it may affect negatively queries filtering, for example, by tweetid only. You can read more about left-most prefix indexes and why your query was doing a full table scan [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: Thanks @jynus! I added a key to user_id but that did not solve it. I wondered whether something happened during the creation of the database, so I decided to generate it again. The problem remains...something wrong is going on. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: > When I select rows by user_id

Can you share the exact query and the output of EXPLAIN in front of it?

Comment: Just edited my post @jynus!

Comment: @Jad I believe what the problem is, but to confirm, can you show also the output of `SELECT count(*) FROM twittertweets` and `SELECT count(*) FROM twittertweets WHERE user_id=3678084920`. Please also add the exact mysql version, you probably are on 5.5 or lower.

Comment: Hey @jynus, thanks for all your help but I found the problem. The index was varchar and I was searching for 3678084920. When this happens, it seems mysql converts 3678084920 to varchar during the search (as it outputs the correct result) but it does not use the index. To use the index, I need to specifically write '3678084920'.

Comment: @Jad Well, I started with "Using a varchar(255) as a 'one-size fits all' type is a bad idea", so do not say I didn't warn you! :-)